Im trying to add a new Entity diagram on visual studio 2022 vb.net language. error "an item with the same key has already been added
I am trying to add a new entity diagram on visual studio 2022. VB.NET. when I generate model from database I am getting this error "an item with the same key has already been added". I tried to close and open visual studio again, I also tried so rebuild and clean my solution
I tried to close and reopen visual studio.
I tried to clean and rebuild my solution.
